# Typo3 6.1.4 / Multishop / No Admin Panel

Tags: typo3

I seem not able to get Multishop running in Typo3 6.1.4, The admin Panel doesn't appear even I have double checked everything. jQuery is loaded only once. User groups and users are set up like in the guide.

When I log into the page, I get no admin panel, just an information box (disappeared after couple of seconds) telling me the following:

> TYPO3 Multishop warnings
>
> This shop doesn't contain any categories.  Click here to add a
>   category
>
> This shop doesn't contain any enabled countries.  Click here to add a
>   country
>
> The store name isn't defined yet.  Go to setup modules and edit the
>   appropriate field
>
> The default meta tag description isn't defined yet.  Go to setup
>   modules and edit the appropriate field

I have no clue what to do else.

Comment: I dont' want to be rude... but have you tried adding categories, enabling a country, defining a name or adding default meta tag description? Have you added static typoscript templates? Have you defined a storage pid? I don't know the extension, so just some ideas.

Comment: thanks, and yes, i have tried all those things, except adding categories, countries and all that stuff which only works from the multishops admin panel, which doesnt show up here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me: http://www.typo3multishop.com/forum/list_post/fix-how-to-make-multishop-compatible-with-typo-6-x-582/ 
(I am using jQuery 1.8.x-1.9.x-1.2.js)

Here the code, in case the link is gone:

Replace:

```
$pageRenderer->addBodyContent(LF . $pageContent);
            if (!empty($GLOBALS['TSFE']->config['INTincScript']) && is_array($GLOBALS['TSFE']->config['INTincScript'])) {
                    // Store the serialized pageRenderer in configuration
                    $GLOBALS['TSFE']->config['INTincScript_ext']['pageRenderer'] = serialize($pageRenderer);
                    // Render complete page, keep placeholders for JavaScript and CSS
                    $GLOBALS['TSFE']->content = $pageRenderer->renderPageWithUncachedObjects($GLOBALS['TSFE']->config['INTincScript_ext']['divKey']);


            } else {
                    // Render complete page
                    $GLOBALS['TSFE']->content = $pageRenderer->render();
            }
```

in typo3/sysext/frontend/Classes/Page/PageGenerator.php by

```
 $pageRenderer->addBodyContent(LF . $pageContent);
            if (!empty($GLOBALS['TSFE']->config['INTincScript']) && is_array($GLOBALS['TSFE']->config['INTincScript'])) {
                    // Store the serialized pageRenderer in configuration
                    $GLOBALS['TSFE']->config['INTincScript_ext']['pageRenderer'] = serialize($pageRenderer);
                    // Render complete page, keep placeholders for JavaScript and CSS
                    $GLOBALS['TSFE']->content = $pageRenderer->renderPageWithUncachedObjects($GLOBALS['TSFE']->config['INTincScript_ext']['divKey']);

                    // Multishop fix
                    $GLOBALS['TSFE']->content = $pageRenderer->render();
            } else {
                    // Render complete page
                    $GLOBALS['TSFE']->content = $pageRenderer->render();
            }
```

credit to Georg Ringer & Bas van Beek

A few other issues I had with the installation of Multishop under Typo3 6.1.x:

- phpexcel_service error --> you have to add that extension first.
- Multishop does not get extracted when using Typo3 extension upload (seems to be too large) --> unpack locally and upload it to typo3conf/ext/multishop

Answer (score 0):

The above patches are not necessary if you update to TYPO3 6.2.X LTS edition.

Also make sure you use the latest GIT version of Multishop, which can be found here:

https://bitbucket.org/bvbmedia/multishop

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem.

My solution: I added the typeNum 2003 and 2002 to the RealUrl configuration (in the ajax calls the &type=200x was missing)

```
    'preVars' => array (
```

...

```
        array(
            'GETvar' => 'type',
            'valueMap' => array(
                'print' => '98',
                'multishop1' => '2003',
                'multishop2' => '2002',
            ),
            'noMatch' => 'bypass',
        ),
```

...

```
    ),
```